# The parameters included in TLS 1.2 server signature in the ServerKeyExchange

Tags: hash, signature, protocol-design, tls

In TLS 1.2, section `7.4.3` [in the standard documentation](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) on `Server Key Exchange Message`, it says that the parameters covered by the digital signature are as follows:

> dh_p
>            The prime modulus used for the Diffie-Hellman operation.
>
> dh_g
>        The generator used for the Diffie-Hellman operation.
>
> dh_Ys
>        The server's Diffie-Hellman public value (g^X mod p).

These parameters are hashed first. My question is: when the hash of these parameters is computed, is it computed over a concatenation of these parameters? or are they combined in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 7.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.3) specifies this:

```
  struct {
      select (KeyExchangeAlgorithm) {
          case dh_anon:
              ServerDHParams params;
          case dhe_dss:
          case dhe_rsa:
              ServerDHParams params;
              digitally-signed struct {
                  opaque client_random[32];
                  opaque server_random[32];
                  ServerDHParams params;
              } signed_params;
          case rsa:
          case dh_dss:
          case dh_rsa:
              struct {} ;
             /* message is omitted for rsa, dh_dss, and dh_rsa */
          /* may be extended, e.g., for ECDH -- see [TLSECC] */
      };
  } ServerKeyExchange;
```

The meaning of `digitally-signed` is explained in [section 4.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4.7). In this case, the above means that the input to the signature algorithm (i.e., that which is hashed) is the concatenation, in that order, of:

- the client random (32 bytes), as sent by the client in the `ClientHello`;
- the server random (32 bytes), as sent by the server in the `ServerHello`;
- the encoding of the `ServerDHParams` structure. This is the complete encoding, including length bytes.

The `ServerDHParams` structure is itself defined as:

```
  struct {
      opaque dh_p<1..2^16-1>;
      opaque dh_g<1..2^16-1>;
      opaque dh_Ys<1..2^16-1>;
  } ServerDHParams;     /* Ephemeral DH parameters */
```

Thus, what goes in the hash function, immediately after the 64 bytes for the client and server randoms, are the two bytes that encode the length of `dh_p`, followed by `dh_p`; then the two bytes for the length of `dh_g`, then `dh_g`; finally, the two bytes for the length of `dh_Ys`, then `dh_Ys`.

Since the `ServerDHParams` structure is itself sent over the wire as part of the `ServerKeyExchange`, it is simpler to think of it as follows: what is signed is exactly the concatenation of the client random, server random, and the bytes encoding the `ServerDHParams`, as sent and received.